# Highlighted image not displayed when user presses on UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView inside of a UIView (takes up the full size of the UIView) and that UIView is itself inside of another UIView (and takes up a small portion of that view's space).

Within IB I have set a different image for the highlighted state and set User Interaction Enabled for the UIImageView, its parent UIView and its grand parent UIView.

However when I tap on the screen the image does not change from the unselected image to the selected image.

[image]

Comment: Why do you this the image will change just by tapping on it? You need to add code to handle the touch and set the image view as highlighted. None of this happens automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UImageViews don't handle touch events. You have to add code if you want them to. The easiest way to do it is with a gesture recognizer.

If you set the highlighted property of your image view to YES through code then you should see the highlighted image.

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

1. Add tap gesture recognizer
2. Create global property `private var switcher = true`
3. Make selector

```html
private func createGesture() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedImageView))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

 @objc private func tappedImageView() {
        imageView.isHighlighted = switcher
        switcher = !switcher
}
```